# Run a PHP file every 5 seconds using Shell Script

Tags: php, shell, sh

I want to run a php file every 5 seconds using Shell Script. But sometimes the script gets run every second or sometimes gets stop running. Do I need to use crontab also? Please help.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    begin=`date +%s`
    php /home/user/www/run.php
    end=`date +%s`
    if [ $(($end - $begin)) -lt 5 ]; then
        sleep $(($begin + 5 - $end))
    fi
done
```

Comment: In my understanding, linux cron can be run in Minutes, Hours, Days, Months , but `NOT` seconds. You should use your shell script , together with `nohup` to run it in background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing would be to configure crontab to keep the execution or another program installed as a service.

The problem with contrab is that the minimum execution is every 1 minute. Therefore, you should create a script that executes every 5 seconds no more than 12 times. (12 x 5 seconds = 60 seconds)

Kill the process and re-run it with crontab.

#### Example

`sript.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Do not run 12 times because this will same time as next crontab execution
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 
do 
    php /home/user/www/run.php
    sleep 5
done
```

On crontab

```sh
* * * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    sleep 5 &
    php /home/user/www/run.php &
    wait
done
```

`wait` (with no arguments) waits for all background jobs to complete, so the loop will block until the *longer* of the sleep and php processes completes.

---

Demonstrating [the SECONDS variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-SECONDS)

```sh
rand() { echo $(( RANDOM % $1 )); }

for i in {1..10}; do
    start=$SECONDS
    r=$(rand 10)
    echo "iteration $i, sleeping for $r seconds"
    sleep $r
    end=$SECONDS
    if ((end - start < 5)); then
        n=$((5 - (end - start)))
        echo "sleep for $n seconds"
        sleep $n
    fi
done

# or more simply by assigning to SECONDS
for i in {1..10}; do
    SECONDS=0
    r=$(rand 10)
    echo "iteration $i, sleeping for $r seconds"
    sleep $r
    duration=$SECONDS
    if ((duration < 5)); then
        n=$((5 - duration))
        echo "sleep for $n seconds"
        sleep $n
    fi
done
```

Certainly more complex than using `wait`

Comment: Additionally, in bash, use the builtin `$SECONDS` variable instead of calling out to `date`, when all you need to do is keep track of durations.